# App Crashing on setting Displacement tilling of texture in SceneKit iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, scenekit, texture-mapping

I can set the tilling of displacement of texture/material through the SceneKit editor, but when I set it through the code like this, It crashes my App.

```
material.displacement.contents = "displacement.png"
material.displacement.contentsTransform = SCNMatrix4MakeScale(10, 10, 0)
material.displacement.wrapT = .repeat
material.displacement.wrapS = .repeat
```

If I comment this line `material.displacement.contentsTransform = SCNMatrix4MakeScale(10, 10, 0)` then it works perfectly but it's not tilling/repeating in that case.

[image]

**Crash Log** : validateFunctionArguments:3341: failed assertion `Vertex Function(commonprofile_vert): argument scn_commonprofile[0] from buffer(3) with offset(0) and length(608) has space for 608 bytes, but argument has a length(672).'

Comment: do you have a crash report?

Comment: @mnuages crash report added to the question.

Answer (score 2):

I was having this problem when I was using .obj files.  When switching to DAE files exported from 3DSMax, the app no longer crashes and I'm able to correctly set Displacement maps on my materials.

It seems like SceneKit has a few bugs around .obj bugs. I've saved myself a lot of hassle by only using DAE files.